# How to add elements of List<T> to a List<T> inline

Tags: flutter, dart

As the children of a `Column` I add e.g. this Widget like so

```
Column(
  children: [
     ... other Widgets above ...
     Chip(
          label: Text(
            myItem.properties['Status'].currentValue,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 10,
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          shadowColor: Colors.grey[60],
        ),
     ... other Widgets below ...
  ]
)
```

Since now I don't have one single `properties['Status']` but several `properties[...]` I want to replace the `Chip(...)` with several `Chip()`s instead.

May I somehow operate on `properties` in such a way, that it returns several `Chip()`s and places it above inline in `Column`s `children` list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the **spread** operator or array destructor operator if you want to use it in line, like this:

```dart
Column(
  children: [
     // ... other Widgets above ...

     // use the spread (...) operator in front of 
     // the mapping method that returns a List<Clip> widgets,
     // and add all chips inside the array
     // assuming that properties['Status'] is an array of some sort

     ...properties['Status'].map((p) {
        
        return Chip(
          label: Text(
            p.currentValue, // consume here the object in the iteration
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 10,
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          shadowColor: Colors.grey[60],
        );

     }).toList(),
     // ... other Widgets below ...
  ]
)
```

Comment: what is "array destructor operator"?
BTW, the .toList() at the end of the spread is not needed. You can spread an Iterator

Comment: "Array destructor" it's just a Javascript concept. Yes, that is true the .toList() at the end is not needed (doesn't hurt either ;) ). I left it there because you can just get rid of the spread operator and simply do **children: properties['Status'].map().toList()** in case you want to just feed it straight up into the Column widget. Thank you for your comment.